# Python scheduler get stuck

Tags: python, schedule

I'm currently using scheduler library for running a task every 4 hours. Generally it works fine but sometimes the main function (or scheduler) get stuck and neither the "life signal" nor the target function is then called anymore. What am I doing wrong?

```
from bot_core import BotCore
import time
import schedule

def life_signal():
    print("{} Scheduler is still running. Waiting for my next job...".format(time.ctime()))

def call_bot():
    bc = BotCore()
    bc.run_core()
    del bc

# Create all new schedulers
scheduler0 = schedule.Scheduler()
scheduler1 = schedule.Scheduler()
scheduler2 = schedule.Scheduler()
scheduler3 = schedule.Scheduler()
scheduler4 = schedule.Scheduler()
scheduler5 = schedule.Scheduler()
scheduler6 = schedule.Scheduler()

# Add jobs to the created schedulers
scheduler0.every(5).minutes.do(life_signal)

scheduler1.every().day.at("02:00:30").do(call_bot)
scheduler2.every().day.at("06:00:30").do(call_bot)
scheduler3.every().day.at("10:00:30").do(call_bot)
scheduler4.every().day.at("14:00:30").do(call_bot)
scheduler5.every().day.at("18:00:30").do(call_bot)
scheduler6.every().day.at("22:00:30").do(call_bot)

while True:
    # Checks whether a scheduled task
    # is pending to run or not
    scheduler0.run_pending()
    scheduler1.run_pending()
    scheduler2.run_pending()
    scheduler3.run_pending()
    scheduler4.run_pending()
    scheduler5.run_pending()
    scheduler6.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: could `call_bot` get stuck?

Comment: no - because sometimes it gets stuck after a few life_signal calls.